# PHP access array value with name

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make a PHP website that gets information out of (a large) array.

The array looks like this:

```
"playerstats": {
        "steamID": "MyID",
        "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
        "stats": [
            {
                "name": "total_kills",
                "value": 35342
            },
            {
                "name": "total_deaths",
                "value": 30465
            },
            {
                "name": "total_time_played",
                "value": 1952281
            so on and so on...
```

The way I'm accessing it right now is by using:

```
$kills = $jsonforgame['playerstats']['stats'][0]['value'];
$deaths = $jsonforgame['playerstats']['stats'][1]['value'];
```

the problem is that I have hundreds of 'stats' in the array, is there a way to access all the value's with the name (like total_kills & total_deaths) instead of having to count all the arrays?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select stats from a multi-dimension array:

```
$searchName = 'total_kills';

$stat = $jsonforgame['playerstats']['stats'][array_search($searchName, array_column($jsonforgame['playerstats']['stats'], 'name'))];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_search`:

```
$stats_array = $jsonforgame['playerstats']['stats'];
$key = array_search('total_deaths', array_column($stats_array, 'name'));
$deaths = $stats_array[$key]['value'];

echo var_dump($key).PHP_EOL;
echo var_dump($stats_array[$key]).PHP_EOL;
echo var_dump($deaths).PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: EDIT: using question's array name.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the structure of your stats array to use the stat name as the array key like so:

```
"playerstats": {
    "steamID": "MyID",
    "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
    "stats": {
        "total_kills": 35342,
        "total_deaths": 30465,
        "total_time_played": 1952281
    }
}
```

Then you can access with

```
$kills = $jsonforgame['playerstats']['stats']['total_kills'];
```

Comment: He isn't asking how to structure the stats, just how to access them.

Comment: And this structure makes them easier to access.  If restructuring the array is an option, this is much easier and more readable.

Comment: This would be the ideal way but I have no influence over the array structure.